# How can I read the body of a SimpleHttpRequest in a HttpRequestInterceptor of the Apache client?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-5.x

I'm using the Apache HttpClient 5.x and can't figure out, how to read the body of a `SimpleHttpRequest` sent by the `CloseableHttpAsyncClient` inside the `process()` method of an `HttpRequestInterceptor`.

This is some sample code of an interceptor:

```
class MyInterceptor implements HttpRequestInterceptor {
  @Override
  public void process(HttpRequest request, EntityDetails entity, HttpContext context) {
    SimpleHttpRequest simpleRequest = (SimpleHttpRequest) request;
  }
}
```

This throws a `ClasCastException` because the actual type of the `HttpRequest` is `BasicHttpRequest` but the `BasicHttpRequest` doesn't have a body.

So how can I access the body of the request inside the interceptor?

Comment: The async part makes this tricky, because the `process` method is called before the body is even full processed. You might be able to get the body directly from the entity. I had one project (not open source, sorry...) where I used an `AsyncExecChainHandler`. That gives you access to the `AsyncEntityProducer`. That's where it gets more complicated though.